# Querying in Entity Framework 4, method querying problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, querying

i have a little misunderstanding and i hope you can clear that for me.
i have a table called : Requests.

I want to do query, lets say by Request Id but it doesn't work.

```
public Requests SearchById(int id)
{
    Model.ModelContainer cont = new Model.ModelContainer();
    return (cont.Requests.Where(req => req.ReqId == id));
    //when i try to cast to Request i get an error too
}
```

i found an example which this line should work :

```
cont.Requests.First(req => req.ReqId == id)
```

but i get error during compilation that it cannot contain lambda expression.

i have few question:

1. How cant i handle the upper example ?(querying from entity)
2. How can i work with multi-line results besides converting to list
3. i need to build and advanced search (i have 6-7 columns ), is there a common way to do it?

thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public Request SearchById(int id)
        {
           using(Model.ModelContainer cont = new Model.ModelContainer())
           {
                return cont.Requests.Where(req => req.ReqId == id).FirstOrDefault();
           }
        }
```

What you had was an `IEnumerable<Request>`, not a single request. Also make sure you have a

```
using System.Linq;
```

in your code file. Also always dispose the context when you can using a `using` block.

```
cont.Requests.First(req => req.ReqId == id)
```

This should also work - make sure you have a `using System.Linq` in your code file.

> How can i work with multi-line results besides converting to list

Since your context is local and not available outside of your method (it gets disposed afterwards) a list is your best option. If you keep it an `IQueryable` then you have not really retrieved the results from the DB yet, you have just defined your query, this leads to a problem when the results are retrieved by the consumer since only then the DB query is executed - but the corresponding DB context might have been disposed already. Append `.ToList()` at the end of your query to materialize an `IQuerable<T>`

> I need to build and advanced search (i have 6-7 columns ), is there a
>   common way to do it?

You can combine multiple clauses in the .Where() extension method, i.e. `Where( x=> x.A=="foo" && x.B == 42)`. You can also chain multiple `Where()` methods if necessary.

Comment: what is the difference between declaring model container with the using

Comment: The `using` block is best practice, but is not required for this to work. While OP should be encourage to use it, I think putting it in this answer is confusing the issue.

Comment: @RonenIL: The resources represented by the context are disposed at the end of the `using` block. Otherwise they will only released when the GC gets to it eventually.

Comment: @RonenIL: added some examples

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `Where` returns a collection of objects (zero to many).  You only want a single object.  You can't simply cast a collection of objects to a single object.

Instead you should get the `First` (or if you know there's definitely going to be only one you can call `Single`).

Regarding 2 - that depends what you want to do. You can do `foreach` over the resultset, or select from the resultset before putting it into a list - but sometimes the most efficient option is to put in a list first.

And point 3, there are plenty of patterns available.  Again it depends on what you're doing and how the 'search terms' work.  For example,

```
public List<Requests> SearchById(int? id, DateTime? date, string name)
{
    var cont = new Model.ModelContainer();
    var query = cont.Requests;

    if (id != null)
        query = query.Where(req => req.ReqId == id.Value);

    if (date != null)
        query = query.Where(req => req.Date == date.Value);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        query = query.Where(req => req.Name == name);

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for ur comment , could you give me a reference for working with collection of object, or give me a simple exmaple for getting the data in the BLL.

Comment: this is for a collection of objects, and I don't know what a BLL is

Comment: i ment that if you could give me a reference how to work with Where results type of even a small example. Business Logic Layer (3-tier design).

Comment: @RonenIL - You're using LINQ, and I recommend <a href="http://www.hookedonlinq.com/">Hooked On LINQ</a> as a resource. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask it, but unless I know what type of problems you're facing I can't really provide guidance.

Comment: hi,again, is there is a way to handle no result with out exception? for this query i get InvaildOperationException : cont.Requests.First(req => req.ReqId == id) with id that doesn't exist

Comment: @RonenIL You can use `FirstOrDefault`, which returns the First item if it exists, otherwise returns the default value for that type (which, for an object, is null).

Comment: and what about Where clause? in your example about the advanced search, if one of the parameters doesn't have results it automaticlly throws InvalidOperationException??

Comment: @RonenIL Not sure what you mean by 'if one of the parameters doesn't have results'. Have a look on some of the many LINQ sites, or find the answer on SO. I'm sure someone has already asked your question.

Comment: i didn't find it there, i meant for example that if i search query = query.Where(req => req.City == city) and the city parameter holds "London" but none of the entries holds that city it throws an exception

Comment: If won't if you do `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: but i want to get all the result (if there are few lines that fits)

Comment: Then use `ToList`, and you'll get a list of matching results. If none match then the list will have 0 items in it.

Comment: hi Kirk, for the above code of yours i get :Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<> to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<>